# Prominent examples of $q$-analogs without known cyclic sieving

Tags: co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory, big-list, q-analogs

The cyclic sieving phenomenon is nicely summarized in the following AMS Notices "What is...?" article: https://www.ams.org/notices/201402/rnoti-p169.pdf.

In that article, Reiner, Stanton, and White explain some desiderata (conditions (i)-(vi)) for "very nice" $q$-analogs $X(q)$ of cardinalities $\#X$ of combinatorial sets.

**Question**: What are some "very nice" $q$-analogs (especially, those with simple product formulas) for which there is no known cyclic action which gives rise to a CSP?

Comment: There is a fairly simple condition on the values of the polynomials at roots of unity that (in principle) guarantees CSP. To clarify, you are looking for examples where there should be a group action, but a nice one has not been discovered yet? Or are you looking for nice q-analogs but the values at roots of unity prevents there to ever be a CSP?

Comment: Is cyclic action known for constant term identities of Dyson/Morris/Aomoto/Forrester type? Or for other root systems counterparts (McDonald conjectures, proved by Cherednik)?

Comment: @PerAlexandersson: I’m more interested in “nice” combinatorial actions than whether in principle some cyclic action exists.

Comment: @FedorPetrov: Those seem like good candidates- I’m not aware of any cyclic sieving results for them.

Answer (score 5):

I think I can provide one example, from [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.01447), *The Cone of Cyclic Sieving Phenomena* by N. Amini and I.

We look at a principal specialization of Schur polynomials,
$$
s_{n \lambda}(1,q,\dotsc,q^k)
$$
for some partition $\lambda$, and integers $n$ and $k$.
Here, $n\lambda = (n\lambda_1,\dotsc,n\lambda_\ell)$.
This polynomial evaluates to non-negative integers at $n$th roots of unity, and I think one should be able to prove without effort that there should in principle be a cyclic group action which gives CSP for this family.

The results by Rhoades show that (a suitable chosen power of) promotion works as group action whenever $\lambda$ is a rectangle.

As a side note, I would be happy to compile a list of suspected instances of [the cyclic sieving phenomenon on my web page](https://www.math.upenn.edu/~peal/polynomials/cyclic-sieving-list.htm#cspList).
At the moment, it lists (most?) published instances of CSP.

I also have a private list with suspected instances, but I prefer to save these for student projects, and a few others I am working on myself.

Comment: Nice example! In addition to Rhoades’s result, I think a result of Stembridge says that for $n=2$ we can take evacuation as the action.

Comment: Wait, the order of promotion should be $k$ (or $k+1$ in your notation), which is unrelated to $n$; so I’m not sure how Rhoades’s result applies here.

Comment: Yes, for $n=2$, evacuation works (it is an involution, of order 2). The order of k-promotion is just plain wrong on non-rectangular shapes. Note, that we deal with SSYT, and not SYT, so one needs to try k-promotion (aka jeu-de-taquin promotion), but yeah, the order is in general huge.

Comment: What I’m saying is that even for $\lambda$ a rectangle, to get cyclic sieving for this polynomial you cannot consider promotion acting on SSYT(n$\lambda$,k) because that has the wrong order (namely, $k$ and not $n$); instead you need to consider promotion acting on SSYT(k$\lambda$,n) or something like that.

Comment: But those sets of SSYT are not quite in bijection. In fact, I don’t see how to play with the parameters to apply Rhoades’s result.

Comment: On pg. 12 of the linked paper you write $s_{n}(1,q,\ldots,q^m) = \binom{n+m-1}{n}_q$ but I think you're off by one here and it should be $s_{n}(1,q,\ldots,q^m) = \binom{n+m}{n}_q$ since $1,q,\ldots,q^m$ is $m+1$ different entries. It is still true that $m$-multisubsets of $\{1,\ldots,n+1\}$ exhibits CSP with respect to the action of the $n$-cycle $(12...n)(n+1)$ (since this is a "Spring regular element"), but this action is less commonly studied than the usual action of the $n+1$-cycle.

Comment: @SamHopkins Ah, you are right, there is an off-by-one error there.